# Qual a melhor maneira de buscar variáveis de ambiente em C# net 6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, variáveis-de-ambiente

Qual a melhor maneira de buscar variáveis de ambiente em C# net 6 ?
Gostaria de saber qual seria a melhor maneira de buscar variáveis de ambiente para uma aplicação web api rest.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Depende o que você quer dizer com "melhor". Existe [uma API pronta pra isso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-6.0)

Comment: vlw Jéf isso aqui ja me ajudou muito!
 Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");

Answer (score 0):

Só pra compartilhar como eu fiz.

Dessa maneira da pra pegar informações primeiro das variáveis de ambiente e se não existir ele busca o default cadastrado em AppSettings.

Program.cs...

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Configuration["AppSettings:Audience"]
```

Ou da pra buscar direto de ambientes mesmo.

```
var Nome = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NomeVariavelDeAmbiente");
```